# How does Taylor's theorem with remainder solve the problem of smooth but not real analytic

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, manifolds, taylor-expansion, smooth-manifolds

Here is the lemma 1.4 from the manifold book by Loring Tu and the lemma is stated as follow:

> Let $f$ be a $C^{\infty}$ function on an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ star-shaped with respect to a point $p=(p^1,...,p^n)$ in $U$. Then there are functions $g_1(x),...,g_n(x)\in C^{\infty}(U)$ such that $f(x)=f(p)+\sum_{i=1}^n(x^i-p^i)g_i(x), g_i(p)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p)$.

I follow the proof but feel confused about the intuitions. It seems this lemma helps solve the problem of functions being smooth but not real analytic by deviating $g_i$ from $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$ of a part of the reminder $R$. But I have two questions:

1. Is it correct that $g_i\neq \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$ since otherwise, it needs a reminder term? In the proof, he stated $g_i(x)=\int_0^1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}(p+t(x-p))dt$.
2. How does it solve functions being smooth but not real analytic, e.g. $f(x)=e^{-1/x}$ for $x>0$ and $0$ otherwise. I try to work $g_1(x)$ out but cannot solve the integration.

Answer (score 1):

1. $g_i$ is not equal to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$ everywhere. It is equal to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}$ at $p$ and it is smooth.
2. For example if you Taylor expand this $f$ at $-1$ and evaluate the expansion at $1$, Taylor's theorem with Lagrange remainder tells you that the error is $\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!} 2^{n+1}$ for some $\xi \in (-1,1)$. The error is of course $e^{-1}$ so you find that $f^{(n+1)}(\xi)$ is $2^{-(n+1)} e^{-1} (n+1)!$. This is possible because $\xi$ can be greater than zero.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! 1 makes sense to me. To be clear, for 2 I mean that $f(x)$ is smooth on $\mathbb{R}$ but does not have a Taylor expansion at $x=0$. The lemma helps us find a special expansion around $x=0$, but I can not write it out i.e. compute $g_1$.

Comment: @quuuuuin It does have a Taylor expansion at $x=0$. That expansion is just equal to zero on the whole line.

Comment: Oh sorry, that means the Taylor expansion at $x=0$, denoted $P(x)=0$, doesn't converge to any point for $x>0$. So does the lemma just distribute the error, i.e. $f(x)-P(x)$ for $x>0$, into each $g_i$ such that we find another expansion that converges to $f(x)$ for $x>0$?